# Why Detox Automation Tool is faster than Appium and others?

Tags: detox

I was searching for some performance comparison e.g. interactions with elements, memory usage, etc with Appium/web driver and others. Unfortunately, I didn't end-up with some concrete benchmarking.

Is there any KPIs on why google/EarlGrey (used by Detox) claims to be faster then others ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detox iOS maintainer here.

Detox is faster because it injects itself inside your app and uses various tricks to monitor when your app is idle or busy, and only blocking test progression when absolutely necessary (e.g. your app is busy with network requests).

This is documented here:
https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.DesignPrinciples.md